# JQuery, updating form and exception if update it more then once

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, jquery, jquery-load

I've got index of my elements:

```
<h2>Index</h2>
    <script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('button').click(function () {
                $.post("Home/Swap", $("#log").serialize(), function (data) {
                    $("#log").load("Home/Index #log");
                });
              });

         }); 
    </script> 

   <form name="list" action="<%=Url.Action("Post", "Home")%>" method="post" id="log">
    <% foreach (var k in Model) { %>
        <input type="checkbox" id="ids" name="ids" value="<%=k.pos%>" /><%= k.pos %>. To jest numer: <%=k.name%><br />
    <% } %>

    </form>
    <button>Swap</button>
```

and Swap method:

```
    public ActionResult Swap(int[] ids)
    {
        int pos1=ids[0];
        int pos2=ids[1];
        Element element1 = (from t in db.Elements
                            where t.pos == pos1
                            select t).Single();
        Element element2 = (from t in db.Elements
                            where t.pos == pos2
                            select t).Single();



        element1.pos = pos2;
        element2.pos = pos1;
        db.SaveChanges();

        return Index();
    }
```

Everything works fine at the first swap of elements. But when I swap it once, and then try to swap another two I get an exception:

> System.NullReferenceException was
>   unhandled by user code
>   Message=Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.

(exception from Swap Method)
It's JQuery problem, Im sure. I susspect this `$("#log").load("Home/Index #log");` line - it shows me right result, but doesn't work fine if I try to do it more then once. how to fix it?

edit: when I refresh page it works the same -> first works well, after getting an exception (the first touched elements are swaped after refreshing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do [`.load("url selector")`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) it *gets* that element, not the *contents* of that element, so you end up with a nested `<form>`, so instead create a wrapper and load that wrapper, so you *replace* the `<form>`, like this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<form name="list" action="<%=Url.Action("Post", "Home")%>" method="post" id="log">
  <% foreach (var k in Model) { %>
    <input type="checkbox" id="ids" name="ids" value="<%=k.pos%>" /><%= k.pos %>. To jest numer: <%=k.name%><br />
  <% } %>
  </form>
</div>
<button>Swap</button>
```

Then load *that* element instead, so you're replacing the `<form>`, like this:

```
$(function () {
  $('button').click(function () {
    $.post("Home/Swap", $("#log").serialize(), function (data) {
      $("#wrapper").load("Home/Index #log");
    });
  });
});
```